# Restar dias en php

Tags: php

Tengon en una variable los dias de vencimiento y lo tengo que hacer que muestre los dias que faltas para vencer.

```
<?php
$fechaApertura = '02/08/2018';
$fechaVencimiento = '08/11/2018';
$dias = 6; //6 dias por vencer
$restaDias = $fechaVencimiento - $dias;
echo "Faltan ".$restaDias." dias para el vencimiento";
?>
```

Lo que da como resultado 2 dias, pero en realidad todavia faltan 6. No sé como hacerlo y mil disculpas por eso.

Comment: No entiendo el problema, si ya sabés que son 6 días (porque lo restás), para que hacés la resta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el siguiente procedimiento:

```
<?php
$fechaApertura = date_create('2018-08-02');
$fechaVencimiento = date_create('2018-11-08');
$interval = date_diff($fechaApertura, $fechaVencimiento);
echo $interval->format('%R%a días');
?>
```

Comment: Gracias gustavo, pero eso me da como resultado `+98` dias y cuando cambio el formato de fecha `02/11/2018` me da `+189` dias. Uno de los problemas es que el sistema ya esta con ese formato de fecha y el otro es que no consigo restar los dias

Comment: Te da ese tiempo porque son varios meses de diferencia si lo verificas hermano. Tienes mes 8 y el otro mes 11.

Comment: Tienes razón, no vi el mes, me he equivicado, pero como hago para cambiar el formato de fecha a **02/11/2018**?

Comment: Puedes usar `$newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("2018-08-02"));` @Daap

Comment: Gracias, vi que era mas simple, lo cambie todo con otro formato de fecha, voy a aplicar lo que me has compartido para mostrar los dias en el panel. Mil gracias!